# go: how to pass directional channels to a function accepting bidirectional channel?

Tags: go

Hi have a function accepting `chan []byte` (that, since no direction is specified I understand it is bidirectional).  The function does not send or receives anything, only looks at number of elements in the channel for stats related purposes.

I want to call this function within a function with following signature:

```
func foo(fooChannel chan<- []byte)
```

But when I try to use argument to call the other function I got the error `cannot use fooChannel (type <-chan []byte) as type chan []byte in function argument`.

Is there any way to cast fooChannel to `chan []byte`?

Since I am only interested in getting some stats, how should I prototype the function to accept any type of channel (so I can get rid even of the "byte" part)? I am only using `len` and `cap` with channels received as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrased a bit:

"Is there a way to cast a directed channel to an undirected?" No there isn't.

"Is there a notion of 'arbitrary channel' (without element type) in Go?" No there isn't. Go has no generics.

You'll have to write several functions.

Comment: That or pass your stats function the len(ch) and cap(ch) values

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to cast fooChannel to chan []byte?

No, sorry. This is probably just in case someone thinks they would like to send on the receiving channel anyway. But, just a little tiny thing, but... No.

> The function does not send or receives anything, only looks at number of elements in the channel for stats related purposes. [...] I am only using `len` and `cap` with channels received as arguments.

If it doesn't use the channel in any channel-ish way, you could simply pass `len(ch)` and `cap(ch)` directly as the arguments. If you don't like it for any reason, you can play with [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package, which will allow you to call `len` and `cap` on any type supporting it (array, channel, slice).

This might be a good start:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func stats(i interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    fmt.Printf("%s size: %d/%d\n", v.Kind(), v.Len(), v.Cap())
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 10)
    ch <- 1
    stats(ch)
}

// Output: chan size: 1/10
```

http://play.golang.org/p/2ehYvEmDkS